# How to remove underline from BasicTextField?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How I can remove underline from my `TextField`? I don't want to use different `TextField()`

```
val style = TextStyle(
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    fontSize = 16.sp,
    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
    textDecoration = TextDecoration.None,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
)

BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .align(Alignment.Center),
    textStyle = style,
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { value = it },
    singleLine = true
)
```

Comment: Does this help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780722/jetpack-compose-how-to-remove-edittext-textfield-underline-and-keep-cursor

Comment: No, it doesn't. I've seen that question before

Comment: @Wafi_ck What does it mean: *I don't want to use different TextField()*. In your question you are talking about TextField but in the code you are using a BasicTextField. Which component do you want to use?

Comment: Yeah, you"re right. I meant I want to use BasicTextField(), not any different type OutlinedTextField() or TextField()