How to disable Android Compose BasicTextField underline
Is there a way to remove the Hello underline in BasicTextField?

Here is the BasicTextField code.
BasicTextField(
value = bodyText.value,
onValueChange = { input ->
    bodyText.value = input
},
modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .padding(),
textStyle = CustomTextStyle.Title9,
decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Box {
            innerTextField()
            if (bodyText.value.isEmpty()) {
                Text(
                    "게시글을 적어주세요.", style = CustomTextStyle.Title9, color = CustomColor.Gray
                )
            }
        }
    }
},

)

have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780722/jetpack-compose-how-to-remove-edittext-textfield-underline-and-keep-cursor
